# Dialogflow with expo cli

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo, dialogflow-es

I found a tutorial on creating a chat bot using react native but it doesn't work with expo cli. I need a way to solve this so that I can integrate it in my application

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you are using the [react-native-dialogflow](https://github.com/innFactory/react-native-dialogflow) package which includes [react-native-voice](https://github.com/react-native-voice/voice) you have to add the following to your `app.config.js`

```
{
  "expo": {
    "plugins": ["@react-native-voice/voice"]
  }
}
```

Please note that those packages are not available in Expo Go.